# Linq to SQL get updated record in transaction

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

I am new to Linq to Sql. I got a scenario. I have two tables. MasterTable and DetailTable table. What I am trying to do is :

Inserting new rows in the DetailTable and on base of DetailTable rows I am trying to Update Master in One transaction.

Here is my code :

```
DBContext context = new DBContext();
context.Connection.Open();
context.Transaction = context.Connection.BeginTransaction();

DetailTable detail = new DetailTable();

detail.Amount = 100;

var detailTable = context.GetTable<DetailTable>();
                // pass in the object with insert on submit
                // and then submit changes
detailTable.InsertOnSubmit(detail);

var result = (from Total in context.MasterTable
select Total).Sum();

decimal total = (decimal)result; // This total is not the latest.

// UpdateMaster.....
// ................

context.SubmitChanges();
context.Transaction.Commit();
```

Now the problem, I am facing is that I am not getting the latest Sum from MasterTable. Like after inserting new row of amount 100, say I should get 600 but I am getting 500 (Sum rows as if I have not inserted new row). 
Please let me know if this is possible using Linq to Sql if it is then how or I am trying to achieve something which is not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to put the `context.SubmitChanges();` above the `decimal total = (decimal)result;`

Comment: Then the transaction will be committed. Suppose if some exception happens what will be the result?

Comment: Read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/679870/linq-to-sql-is-it-true-that-submitchanges-automatically-starts-a-transaction

Comment: I know how the SubmitChanges works. Suppose I update Detail and call SubmitChanges and something happens while updating the Master. The detail changes will be saved to the database and my data will be in a bad state.

Comment: I am surprised that SubmitChanges worked in this scenario. But it worked if you put SubmitChanges before                                 var result = (from Total in context.MasterTable
select Total).Sum();

Answer (score 1):

The data in your datacontext is stale. Linq-2-sql will not apply pending updates before your submitchanges.

So what you need to do is either the following:

```
decimal total = (decimal)result + detail.amount
```

or you do indeed what Jan P. has suggested above. That will work too since you are managing the transaction yourself.

Additionally: why are you opening the connection yourself? There is no need to do so in this case.

Comment: This is pseudo code man. Actually connection open code is in DAL. My DAL was giving error that connection is not opened so I did manually.